# Phonegap/Cordova running on a mobile device

Tags: ios, cordova

How can I test if the site is running on a mobile device? What's the equivalent to the old Phonegap.available? Since I switched from PhoneGap 1.3.0 to Cordova 1.7.0 it doesn't work, I tried.

```
window.cordova
```

But this also returns true on a desktop browser.

Comment: will the user open the site from the mobile browser by typing the URL or will it be an on-device app (a mobile hybrid app) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `device.cordova`. See reference [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_device_device.md.html#device.cordova)

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an event for `deviceready`, which will only occur if the application is being run from a mobile device:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady()
{
    alert("We're mobile!");
}
```

Comment: I doubt, it works only if it is a Hybrid app, what if the site is opened from a Mobile Browser by the user ?

Comment: It is not an event fired by the browser, it is an event fired by Phonegap/Cordova.

Comment: Your phonegap JS runs inside a browser alone and its events will get fired only if the app is a hybrid app. Check the docs plz

Answer (score 0):

Just if someone google it:

```
PhoneGap.available
```

is replaced by:

```
device.available
```